# How to display a custom form in a newly created template page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I do have a `hook_form` in my custom module and also have a customized `page.tpl.php` file .Is there any way by which you can pass the form to the tpl page.I thought of passing the $form variable to the tpl page through the `hook_theme` function but that is quite not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard method is to use a preprocess function, either in your theme or module

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['some_form'] = drupal_get_form('MYMODULE_some_form');
}
```

Then in the template file:

```
<?php echo $some_form; ?>
```

You'll need to clear the caches after implementing the hook for the theme registry to pick it up.